# div appearing next to wrapper that contains elements with float: left...?

Tags: css

I was trying to figure this out but no luck...

**My problem:**

I have 3 divs, `wrapper`, `floatleft` and `normal`

where `wrapper` is wrapping the `floatleft` divs and `normal` is outside the wrapper and is completely normal div without any styling

The problem is that the `normal` div is appearing next to float left divs instead of appearing under the `wrapper`... Why?

Code/Example : http://jsfiddle.net/kaAjW/3969/

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.clearfix`.

You always need to clear given float's to elements.

Define a clearfix class and call it in wrapper.

```
.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}

<div class='wrapper clearfix'>
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/kaAjW/3975/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the float element, if the wrapper contains just the float it doesn't have height or width because floating elemnts doesn't occupy space if you inpect de DOM you will that the wrapper have 0width and 0 height. You have to look for a clearfix solution, google it and you can find many examples of css clearfix solution. With that you will put a clearfix class to the wrapper div to make it have the size of the floating div.

Answer (score 2):

Use `float:left` on your wrapper and give it `width:100%`

```
.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  float:left;
}
```

This is the easiest fix. I'd recommend looking into [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) - it solves all those issues for you

Answer (score 2):

The float property specifies whether or not an element should `float`.
The clear property is used to control the behaviour of floating elements.check this  [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kaAjW/3979/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `overflow:hidden` for the container wrapper or clearfix hack http://jsfiddle.net/kaAjW/3976/